# Send data from Google Sheets to a webhook url in json format on trigger column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, webhooks

Is there a way to **trigger** an *action* (i.e convert row data into json format and send it to a **webhook URL**)  from Google Sheets based on column values like *dates*?

Triggers like when todays date equals date in column?

WEBHOOK REQUEST EXAMPLE DATA

```
{
    "data": {
        "header_image_url": "https:\/\/..."
    },
    "recipients": [
        {
            "whatsapp_number": "+91XXXXXXXXXX",
            "attributes": {
                "first_name": "James",
                "last_name": "Bond"
            },
            "lists": [
                "Default"
            ],
            "tags": [
                "new lead",
                "notification sent"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: About the trigger, if you want to run the script when the cells are edited, I think that OnEdit and OnChange triggers can be used. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) And, although, unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand the specification of your webhook, when you want to request the HTTP request, I think that Class UrlFetchApp can be used. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, can you provide the specification of your webhook? Unfortunately, I cannot know the specification of your webhook. And, unfortunately, I cannot understand `i.e convert row data into json format and send it to a webhook URL` and `Triggers like when todays date equals date in column?`. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected goal?

Comment: Please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers. If you need further help please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This example uses the [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger. When the condition: A1 content is `Send`, it makes a POST request using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) to your endpoint.

```js
const sS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
function onEdit(e) {
  const data = { "data": "SOME_DATA" }
  const { range } = e
  if (range.getColumn() === 1
    && range.getRow() === 1
    && range.getValue() === "Send") {
    UrlFetchApp.fetch("URL_ENDPOINT", {
      method: "POST",
      "content-type": "application/JSON",
      "payload": JSON.stringify(data)
    })
  }
}
```

You only need to edit it to suit your needs. Also you can create a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) to trigger the action.

##### Documentation:

- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)